# Nested multiple request with dispatch_group

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to make multiple requests to server to fetch posts and comments one after another. So, I created this example with dispatch_group which fetches all the POSTS serially one after another and then after it finished with the POSTS, it fetches comments one after another.

Here is a rough schema about how this works.

- Fetch post 1
- Fetch post 2
- Fetch post 3
- ....
- Fetch post 50
- Fetch comment 1
- Fetch comment 2
- ...
- Fetch comment 50

So, all these should work serially as shown, like it fetches post 1, finishes with that and then fetches post 2 finish and so on.

The following example works fine for the purpose. But, now I would want to have a call back to actually know when syncing of 50 posts were finished and when 50 comments were finished. I tried that by adding dispatch_group_notify after for loop in requestOne and requestTwo. But, the notify method seems to be called when all the tasks have been completed. How can that be achieved ? I am not native English speaker so, please write down if I need to improve the post, I can still try :)

```
@interface GroupTest ()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_group_t group;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;

@end


@implementation GroupTest

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _group = dispatch_group_create();
        _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.serial.queue",
                                             DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    dispatch_async(self.serialQueue, ^{

        [self requestOneCompletion:^{
            NSLog(@"Request 1 completed");
        }];

        [self requestTwoCompletion:^{
            NSLog(@"Request 2 completed");
        }];

    });
}
- (void)requestTwoCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
        [self requestComment:i
               completion:^(id response){
                   NSLog(@"%@", response);
                   dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
               }];
        dispatch_group_wait(self.group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }

}


- (void)requestOneCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
        [self requestPost:i
               completion:^(id response){
                   NSLog(@"%@", response);
                   dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
               }];
        dispatch_group_wait(self.group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
}

- (void)requestComment:(NSUInteger)comment
            completion:(void(^)(id))completion
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/%lu", (unsigned long)comment];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
           completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
               id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:nil];
               completion(object);
           }];
    [dataTask resume];

}

- (void)requestPost:(NSUInteger)post
         completion:(void(^)(id))completion
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/%lu", (unsigned long)post];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
           completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
               id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:nil];
               completion(object);
           }];
    [dataTask resume];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is the following. Note that this is made so each completion block for `requestTwoCompletion` and `requestOneCompletion` will be called after all 50 calls are done. The order of the 50 calls are not guaranteed.

The main changes I made were the `dispatch_group_t` is local to each method and I moved `dispatch_group_wait` outside of the `for` loop. In this case it takes away the benefit of `completion` since the wait will block unit it is done. If you are highly insistent on completion being used and it not blocking, you can wrap this all in a `dispatch_async`.

```
- (void)requestTwoCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [self requestComment:i
               completion:^(id response){
                   NSLog(@"%@", response);
                   dispatch_group_leave(group);
               }];
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    completion();
}


- (void)requestOneCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [self requestPost:i
               completion:^(id response){
                   NSLog(@"%@", response);
                   dispatch_group_leave(group);
               }];
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

As this is in a serial queue, the way this will work is `requestOneCompletion` will finish all 50, and then `requestTwoCompletion` will run all 50 next.